# python decorators in asyncio event listener with Telethon

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, telethon

Every time a message is sent to the channel the handler function will be called because of the python decorator.
I want to to both recieve messages and print them out. This is how i imagined the program should look like.

But its not working because the event is not passed to the handler function in main.
How can i do that asynchronously, when the @client decorator is controlling the messages and stopping me from using using the handler function inside other functions, and pass on the tokenData

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
channel = 'https://t.me/DEXTNewPairsBotBSC'


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel))
async def handler(event):
    # tokenData = event
    tokenData = event.message.message
    msg.append(tokenData)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return tokenData


async def dumpIt():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return msg[0]

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(handler(event))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(dumpIt())
    await asyncio.wait([task1,task2])


client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: better run `dumpIt(tokenData)` directly in `handler()` - it is only way to run `dumpIt` when handler get new message

Answer (score 0):

Use [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html):

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = ...
queue = asyncio.Queue()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel))
async def handler(event):
    queue.put_nowait(event.message.message)


async def dumpIt():
    msg = await queue.get()
    return msg

async def main():
    await dumpIt()

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

As long as the `asyncio` event loop is running (which it is while it's "blocked" in `queue.get()`), Telethon will receive updates.